# Using python, how can I import a CSV to an existing Excel worksheet?

Tags: python, excel, csv

I'm trying to use python to replace the contents of a sheet in an existing Excel workbook by importing data from a CSV. Ideally refreshing any pivot tables with the new data too.

How could I go about doing this?

```
excel_file = r'S:\Andy\Python\Monthly Report.xlsx'
sheet_name = r'Raw Data'
csv_path = r'S:\Andy\Python\Data Export.csv'
```

Comment: I recommend reading this guide: https://realpython.com/openpyxl-excel-spreadsheets-python/ and then trying your own approach, If your own approach doesn't work, you can ask for help on Stack Overflow.

Comment: You could try using `pandas`, with it you can read excels and csv documents, and has many useful functions to handle tables.